# Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Date nest js unit testing

Tags: unit-testing, date, nestjs, crud

I created a sample project with CRUD using NestJs. I create a User with a randomly generated `Id`, `name`, `birthdate` and `email`. I need to do unit testing for this create CRUD operation. But I do not know how to test the birthDate. It gives me an error.

[This is what I got when I tried to pass the date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPHWr.png)

**User Entity:**

```js
import {
  Column,
  CreateDateColumn,
  Entity,
  PrimaryGeneratedColumn,
} from 'typeorm';

@Entity('users')
export class User {
  //auto increment
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('increment')
  id: number;

  @Column({ nullable: true, default: null })
  name: string;

  @CreateDateColumn({ nullable: true })
  birthDate: Date;

  @Column({ type: 'varchar' })
  email: string;
}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow ! A few topics before answering: 1) think about sending your error message as text instead of an image with the request, so that we have quick access to the problem. 2) check out your syntax and formatting. 3) what did you try beforehand to solve your problem ?

Comment: Thank you for your kind words. I tried DATE('2000.6.7'). How can I convert this String value to a DATE data type?

Answer (score 1):

You're passing a `string`, but typescript expect `Date`.

try changing `birthDate: '2000.6.7'` to `birthDate: new Date('2000-06-07')`.

Comment: Oh thank you so much.It got resolved